# Please help me to identify this creature, is it harmful and possible solution of how to get rid of these in my house

Tags: species-identification, entomology, pest-control

Please help me to identify this creature, is it harmful and possible solution of how to get rid of these in my house.

Please forgive me for bad image quality, some of these have white dot at the back(I guess male/female identification mark).
I am from north India, Punjab region
Please help me to get rid of these.

min size found: 3mm

max size found: 6-7mm

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: These look like mealybugs (Hemiptera: Sternorrhyncha: Coccoidea: Pseudococcidae); if so, then you have an infested houseplant (you're implying they're indoors).  Step one is to identify the houseplant that is harboring the animals; after that, I don't have much to tell you (I'm not an economic entomologist).

Comment: they are both indoor and outdoor, first these were out of my house, then I found these inside too. I don't have plants inside house but I do have flowering plants in my gallary, inside house but outside our living areas. I am not sure if they are really mealybugs, as they don't look much like them and I could not find any plant with these. these are mostly on wall and floor